# Updating Entity Framework without Nuget from Vs2010 to Vs2015

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

Just started working at a company where they are planning on taking an existing project and revamping it. The project is a windows form built in C# and communicates with a an app for windows mobile 6.5, then relays all the information from the app to a database for a management application. It uses .Net 4.0 with Entity Framework 4.0.

I am going to be working on this and the first thing we would like to do is migrate this project from VS2010 to VS2015; however, whenever I try to do this directly, I have errors show up about references missing. I have double checked the .Net targets for all the projects in the solution and all match.

I have also tried going from VS2010 to VS2012 to hopefully take it a step at a time; however, the same errors show up as before.

I have tried:

- Setting up the targets for each project in the solution
- Installing NuGet, but it cannot find Entity Framework in the porject
- Package Manager Console, but it can never find any version of entityframework
- When Get-Package is typed into Package Manager Console, No packages installed returns
- Installing it manually, but there is no EntityFramework.dll in the solution folders

This project does have entity framework as System.Data.Entity is included and from the looks of it, it has the entity framework api and calls.

Specific Errors:

- When opening in VS2015, "sync.designer.cs" cannot be saved because it is write protected. I tried selecting all folders and removing the read-only permission
- When trying to build, The type or namespace name could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) but the file is using the namespace where this 'missing' file is

Comment: What are the errors specifically?

Comment: Can you list the reference errors?

Comment: When opening in VS2015, "sync.designer.cs" cannot be saved because it is write protected. I tried selecting all folders and removing the read-only permission. When trying to build, The type or namespace name could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) but the file is using the namespace where this 'missing' file is

Comment: The Sync Framework designers are not supported in newer versions of Visual Studio